# Code compiling in eclipse but not on command line

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, eclipse-3.3

I once wrote this line in a Java class. This compiled fine in Eclipse but not on the command line.

This is on

- Eclipse 3.3
- JDK 1.5
- Windows XP Professional

Any clues?

Error given on the command line is:

```
Icons.java:16: code too large
            public static final byte[] compileIcon = { 71, 73, 70, 56, 57, 97, 50,
                                       ^
```

The code line in question is:

```
public static final byte[] compileIcon = { 71, 73, 70, 56, 57, 97, 50,
            0, 50, 0, -9, 0, 0, -1, -1, -1, -24, -72, -72, -24, -64, -64,
            -8, -16, -24, -8, -24, -24, -16, -24, -32, -1, -8, -8, 48, 72,
            -72, -24, -80, -80, 72, 96, -40, -24, -24, -8, 56, 88, -56,
            -24, -40, -48, -24, -48, -64, 56, 80, -64, 64, 88, -48, -56,
            -64, -64, -16, -24, -24, -32, -40, -40, -32, -88, -96, -72,
            -72, -72, -48, -56, -56, -24, -32, -32, -8, -8, -1, -24, -40,
            -56, -64, -72, -72, -16, -32, -40, 48, 80, -72, -40, -96, -104,
            -40, -96, -96, -56, -104, -104, 120, 88, -104, -40, -64, -80,
            -32, -88, -88, -32, -56, -72, -72, -80, -80, -32, -80, -88,
            104, -96, -1, -40, -40, -40, -64, -104, -104, -32, -56, -64,
            -112, 104, 112, -48, -104, -112, -128, -112, -24, -72, -80,
            -88, -8, -8, -8, -64, -112, -120, 72, 104, -40, 120, 96, -96,
            -112, -96, -24, -112, -120, -72, -40, -88, -88, -48, -64, -72,
            -32, -72, -80, -48, -72, -88, -88, -72, -24, 64, 88, -56, -120,
            96, 104, 88, -128, -72, 48, 56, 56, 104, 104, 120, 112, -120,
            -16, -128, 104, -88, -40, -48, -48, 88, -120, -24, 104, 88,
            -104, -40, -56, -72, -128, 112, -88, -128, 96, -88, -104, -88,
            -24, -96, -120, 120, -88, -128, -80, -56, -56, -64, 96, 120,
            -8, -96, -128, -88, -80, -96, -104, -32, -72, -72, 96, 104,
            112, 96, -104, -8, -72, -112, -112, -64, -72, -80, 64, 64, 72,
            -128, -120, -96, -128, 88, 88, -56, -72, -80, 88, 96, 120, -72,
            -128, 112, 72, 112, -40, 96, 120, -56, 88, -112, -16, 64, 104,
            -48, -64, -80, -88, -88, -120, -80, 88, 88, 96, -56, -96, -120,
            -40, -56, -64, 96, 104, 120, -120, -80, -24, -104, -88, -40,
            -48, -72, -80, -64, -56, -16, -88, -112, -128, -32, -48, -56,
            -24, -16, -8, -64, -120, 120, -96, -96, -88, 80, -128, -24,
            -56, -72, -88, -96, 120, 88, -72, -112, 120, -64, -104, 120,
            -48, -56, -64, -120, -104, -32, -104, 120, -80, -96, -112,
            -120, 56, 88, -64, -128, 96, 64, 88, 120, -40, -80, -104, -120,
            -104, -128, 104, 96, -104, -24, -72, -120, -128, 56, 96, -56,
            -128, 112, 104, -48, -88, -112, 96, 96, 104, -104, -88, -72,
            -40, -88, -96, -72, -88, -96, -120, 120, 104, -80, -88, -96,
            72, 72, 80, -120, 88, 96, 120, -120, -24, 96, -104, -16, 104,
            80, 48, -56, -80, -96, -56, -88, -104, -104, 120, -88, -88,
            120, 104, -72, -120, -120, -24, -32, -40, 112, 88, -104, 120,
            96, -104, -32, -32, -32, -96, 96, 96, 80, 80, 88, 64, 88, 120,
            72, 120, -40, 72, 88, 112, -88, -96, -104, -56, -80, -88, -72,
            -88, -104, -56, -64, -72, -80, -120, 104, -80, -120, -80, -112,
            112, -88, 120, 112, 112, 112, -96, -24, -120, -120, -64, -120,
            120, -80, 64, 96, -128, 96, 64, 64, 96, -128, -32, 80, 112,
            -24, 112, -120, -24, 104, -96, -8, 96, 120, -16, -88, 120, 120,
            -72, -56, -16, -128, -128, -128, -104, -120, -72, -64, -96,
            -120, -32, -64, -64, -40, -48, -56, -64, -88, -96, -64, -104,
            -72, -96, -88, -24, -104, -96, -40, -96, -128, 96, -128, -128,
            -96, 104, 88, 80, 112, -88, -8, -64, -104, -80, -96, -120, 112,
            96, 120, -32, 56, 80, -72, -104, -88, -32, 104, -128, -24, -56,
            -88, -120, -80, -72, -8, -96, -128, -128, -64, -128, 96, -72,
            -96, -120, 72, 104, -32, -96, 96, 64, -72, -96, -112, -32, -40,
            -48, -64, -88, -112, -88, -128, 96, -88, -128, -88, -64, -64,
            -32, -128, -96, -32, -88, -104, -112, 32, 32, 64, -120, 104,
            -88, 120, -120, -16, -104, 120, -72, -24, -48, -56, -96, -96,
            -96, -64, 96, 96, 96, 64, 32, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 44, 0, 0, 0, 0,
            50, 0, 50, 0, 0, 8, -1, 0, 1, 8, 28, 72, -80, -96, -63, -125,
            8, 19, 42, 92, -120, 112, 0, 3, 6, 12, 23, 6, -104, 72, -79,
            -94, -59, -117, 19, 39, -124, 64, -128, -128, 3, -121, 9, 19,
            48, -118, -92, 24, 81, 33, -118, 8, 40, 7, -88, 84, -55, -64,
            12, 6, 6, 45, 74, -54, 52, 8, 73, -60, 24, 22, 25, 92, 73, 40,
            64, -96, -64, 74, -121, 24, 94, -58, -100, 25, -79, -59, 47,
            17, 3, 52, -120, 88, -125, 105, 73, 6, 42, -102, -68, 96, -16,
            -71, 18, 3, -118, 6, 13, 14, -114, -36, 26, -64, 69, 7, 18, 28,
            -61, -110, -32, -32, -62, -54, -94, 72, -61, -48, -88, -40, 72,
            34, -60, 4, 21, 23, -119, 14, -92, 80, -58, 6, -108, 10, 18,
            44, 68, -8, 57, -96, -128, 16, 98, 70, -24, -48, 97, -45, 6, 4,
            6, 16, 67, -27, 18, 52, -79, -52, -89, -46, 49, -105, -74, -32,
            109, -45, -85, -63, -49, 2, 13, 88, -51, -62, 5, 40, 80, 31,
            91, 103, 20, 11, -116, 32, -124, -81, -54, 2, 40, -58, -40,
            -103, -59, -122, 13, 43, 51, 12, 122, 106, 96, -48, 0, -105,
            40, 29, 106, 32, 17, 20, -64, -69, -73, -17, -33, -68, 25, 113,
            13, 80, -125, 44, -102, 72, 108, -84, -88, 80, 49, -127, -61,
            -94, 28, -97, -108, -4, -98, -103, 102, 9, -127, -21, -40, -81,
            23, -32, 35, -126, 39, -10, 2, 32, -116, 29, -1, 27, -74, 37,
            -40, 29, 60, 90, -60, -120, -90, 0, -122, -118, -23, -107, 54,
            -36, -72, -15, 2, 66, -61, -23, -39, 24, -8, -36, -7, -108,
            -27, -128, 44, -59, -112, -16, -64, 67, 3, -39, 21, 72, 0, 6,
            34, 120, -31, -123, 124, 124, 52, 16, 84, 3, -119, -88, 82,
            -62, 28, -2, 21, 4, -36, -123, -83, -92, -96, 97, 13, 20, 117,
            112, 2, -121, 24, 77, -128, 6, 48, -64, 72, -93, -62, 31, 104,
            -56, 48, 68, 16, 65, 112, 49, 29, 67, 82, 8, 24, 72, 118, 18,
            84, 48, 66, 6, 63, 72, 96, 96, 1, 26, -128, 64, -97, 8, 50, 24,
            114, -64, -112, -22, -51, -28, 7, 24, 77, 116, -15, 75, 1, 123,
            53, 2, -63, 15, 22, 88, 0, 1, 5, 44, 72, 32, -127, 74, -78,
            -47, -122, -62, 27, -90, -24, 49, -28, 1, 69, -106, -108, 76,
            21, -99, 8, -127, -119, 29, -81, 60, 41, -63, 15, 16, -116, 80,
            65, -114, 22, -44, 40, 72, 6, 111, 60, 4, 77, 3, 34, -124, 1,
            -60, -105, 7, 40, 96, -31, -123, -68, 49, -111, 66, 30, 32,
            102, -92, 66, 30, 86, 60, -47, -63, 12, 30, 42, 58, 67, 13, 51,
            120, -32, 1, 35, 30, 112, 112, -62, 39, -114, -80, 24, -124,
            116, 47, 30, 116, 6, 15, -120, 24, -104, 93, 3, -105, 44, -79,
            12, 11, -103, -116, 112, 35, 20, 52, -96, 64, 3, 32, 91, -40,
            -1, 114, 5, -97, 126, -106, 36, 5, 24, -106, -67, 103, 26, 3,
            32, -68, -14, 10, 20, 44, 88, -78, -124, 37, 91, -124, -47,
            -33, -105, 112, -56, -28, 7, -103, -70, -86, 116, -57, 29, 52,
            80, 37, -101, 8, 54, 24, 99, -121, 17, 82, -108, -80, 0, -83,
            7, 93, 56, 70, 14, 41, -96, -78, -107, 11, -117, -48, 97, -42,
            12, 127, 32, 64, 66, 91, 19, -96, -88, -94, 35, -16, 110, 10,
            -88, 65, 103, 76, -62, 67, 19, 114, -120, -102, 93, 49, 107,
            -108, 65, -121, 29, -121, -36, 65, -116, 16, 24, -32, 121,
            -125, 33, -70, 108, -96, 112, -97, 37, 5, -127, 100, 23, -128,
            -4, 68, 65, 5, 123, -103, 102, -63, 24, 101, -20, 49, -51, 33,
            -121, -40, 80, 65, 9, 122, 40, -84, 112, -78, 17, 73, 81, 69,
            -110, -110, -28, -38, -105, 9, 84, -30, 69, 21, -106, 60, 106,
            32, 68, 25, -127, -96, -96, -25, 6, 14, 56, -96, 112, -83, 90,
            81, 116, 2, -72, 57, 16, 66, 8, 88, 28, 49, 26, 66, 8, 51, 60,
            -15, -60, 9, 51, -128, -75, -82, 91, 19, 116, 96, -87, 12, 31,
            84, 93, -75, 18, 91, 13, 100, -126, -67, 125, 72, 50, 72, 45,
            63, 89, -112, 1, 5, 20, -104, 96, 65, 1, 38, -4, 48, 49, 4,
            -82, 60, 84, 48, 13, -90, 92, -111, -13, -36, 60, 39, -44, 66,
            40, 96, -12, -47, -59, 32, 81, -20, -1, -15, 19, 4, 18, 68, 80,
            64, 5, 72, -80, 0, -127, 9, 17, 72, -112, 9, 20, -106, -48,
            -48, -86, -79, 56, -49, 77, -14, 66, -76, -100, -68, 119, 20,
            59, 44, -15, 19, -53, 20, 0, 30, 103, -101, 110, -66, 97, -122,
            25, 52, 44, 33, -125, -74, 11, -92, -98, 115, -35, 90, -55, 1,
            52, 33, 83, 76, 33, -118, 10, 97, 73, -70, 81, 7, 29, 44, -35,
            1, -46, 29, 76, -22, 2, 7, 30, -84, 50, -60, 7, 48, 60, 114,
            -11, 112, 0, -124, -95, 67, 21, -110, 96, -66, -61, 14, 12,
            -84, 36, -27, 8, -99, -101, 80, -128, 5, 72, -36, -104, -55,
            23, -92, 83, -95, -116, 19, 14, -92, 46, 62, -21, 8, 21, 1, 68,
            9, -93, -124, -78, 3, 51, 59, -68, -84, 82, -30, 72, 84, 64, 1,
            18, 121, 85, 0, -123, 32, -126, -80, -112, 6, -56, 11, -32, 32,
            -2, -28, 10, -71, -64, 5, -80, 48, 7, 74, 56, -63, 16, 58, -40,
            65, 45, -28, -16, 5, -108, 56, 16, 37, -112, -80, 17, 5, 70,
            -16, 6, 87, 124, -127, 5, -98, 0, -126, 3, 30, -128, -125, 14,
            -30, 64, 1, 2, 12, -95, 8, 67, 8, 0, -118, 108, -126, 8, 31,
            -16, 1, 40, 100, -96, -120, 20, 76, 33, 18, 121, -104, 64, 88,
            102, 24, 2, -78, 48, 66, 5, -101, -96, 26, 12, 118, -72, 67,
            100, 12, 103, 34, 4, 89, 65, 18, -1, 72, -127, -125, 2, 30, 80,
            7, -107, -24, -37, 22, 26, -15, -66, 2, 20, -96, 17, 12, 64,
            65, 52, -30, -74, -128, 7, 88, -47, -118, -28, 99, -120, 2,
            122, -112, -124, 36, -100, 34, 1, 14, -48, -126, 26, 74, -128,
            -121, 80, 68, 33, 10, -127, -80, -127, 6, 98, -122, 1, 42, 120,
            34, 11, 27, -72, -94, 21, 1, 56, 19, 50, 116, -47, -117, -89,
            32, -59, 3, 28, 112, 5, 39, -108, 0, -119, 81, 16, -123, 17,
            108, 96, 6, 42, -8, 65, 91, 15, 72, -128, 28, -77, -120, 16,
            -116, -64, -30, 25, 113, -120, 100, 36, -101, -15, 8, 24, -84,
            80, 6, 46, -116, 93, 36, -124, -9, 1, 34, 120, -46, -109, 71,
            -8, 33, 73, 16, 66, -122, 21, -12, -32, -108, 61, 40, 5, 47,
            18, 48, -121, 62, -2, 113, 18, 58, 112, -62, 6, 18, 64, -53,
            90, 50, 82, 49, 10, 40, -62, 41, 11, -63, 75, 94, -68, 32, 117,
            106, -16, -93, 30, 18, 89, -53, 4, -60, 64, 52, 10, 81, -128,
            47, 86, -64, 76, 102, -106, 34, 23, 47, -48, -126, 22, 28, 80,
            76, 90, -34, 82, 32, 6, -56, -90, 54, 69, 25, 0, 38, -64, -126,
            11, 71, 8, -89, 56, -107, -96, 8, 31, -104, -45, 7, 68, -32, 2,
            55, -127, 72, -108, 11, -112, -95, 8, 49, -120, -89, 60, 71,
            -15, -126, 122, 38, -32, -102, -56, 60, -120, 2, 110, 80, 51,
            -124, 126, -58, -94, 8, -62, -88, -25, 49, -13, 41, 23, 5,
            -112, -31, 6, 8, 93, 65, 64, -15, -39, -56, 117, 98, -124, 9,
            51, -72, -59, 45, 56, -95, 78, -121, 6, -128, -96, 5, -39, 39,
            67, 49, -54, -47, -114, 122, -44, 32, 1, 1, 0, 59 };
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Taking from [this forum on Sun's support site](http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=747860&messageID=4278559), no method can be more than 64 KB long:

When you have code (pseudo) like the following...

```
class MyClass
{
  private String[] s = { "a", "b", "c"}

  public MyClass()
  {
  }
```

The compiler ends up producing code that basically looks like the following.

```
class MyClass
{
  private String[] s;

  private void FunnyName$Method()
  {
    s[0] = "a";
    s[1] = "b";
    s[2] = "c";
  }
  public MyClass()
  {
    FunnyName$Method();
  }
```

And as noted java limits all methods to 64k, even the ones the compiler creates.

It may be that Eclipse is doing something sneaky to get around this, but I assure you this is still possible in Eclipse because I have seen the same error message.  A better solution is to just read from a static file, like this:

```
public class Icons
{
  public static final byte[] compileIcon;
  static
  {
    compileIcon = readFileToBytes("compileIcon.gif");
  }
  //... (I assume there are several other icons)
  private static byte[] readFileToBytes(String filename)
  {
    try {
      File file = new File(filename);
      byte[] bytes = new byte[(int)file.length()];
      FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(file);
      fin.read(bytes);
      fin.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      System.exit(1);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

What you have seems to compile.

If possible, I would suggest trying to embed the resource in the Jar and using 
    ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream().

Answer (score 3):

Eclipse has it's own compiler. The Eclipse JDT compiler seems to handle your array differently than javac.

Answer (score 2):

Hard to tell why you have command line compilation errors, but ...

Since you have an awful lot of "magic numbers", there may be a better approach than hardcoding an array literal.

Consider

- Using a static initializer block to initialize an List
- Reading an XML file that will have your numbers, and using your class that reads the XML to return the datatype you want (be it a List or byte[]

Answer (score 1):

Providing the exact error message would help us to help you too...
And I wonder why you hard-code an image (icon) in the source, instead of using some form of resource.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say from what's provided, but guesses are

1. Different JVM in Eclipse than command line.
2. Bad classpath settings in command line.

What are the compile errors?

Can you isolate the problem in a dummy class for demonstration?

Answer (score 0):

if you are on windows
write

> set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files.... path to JDK
>   the path should be the jdk path not jre
>   on my PC is C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_07

**WARNING** : THE PATH SHOULD NOT BE NOT SURROUNDED BY QUOTES (") cmd's autocompletions puts them !

on unix like systems use

> export JAVA_HOME=*PATH TO JDK* (quotes are tolerated)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your commandline and eclipse are using same version of Java compiler and same compile setting? To find you what version of Java you are using in command line type: Java -version